# Hibernate getting BatchUpdateException while inserting

Tags: hibernate

I am getting BatchUpdateException while inserting some data with Hibernate. When I try to insert below statement with sql editor It doesn't throws any exception. Is there any idea?

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: 
Batch entry 0 insert into registered_user (alias, id, register_time, title, type, uuid) values ('www.google.com', '0010001774', '2013-12-23T14:13:46', 'Google software', 'Special', 'A39D895E-111B-47E7-AFCD-25125556A0A0') 
was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.

    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1837)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2754)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:110)
```

Comment: Is there any other exception or this is the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem. First remove the batch update and run the application to see full stacktrace. Then after solve the problem add batch update again. I think there is no way to full stacktrace with batch update enabled.